# How to add class to Vue component via $refs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I need to add class name to some Vue components using their ref names. The ref names are defined in a config file. I would like to do it dynamically, to avoid adding class manually on each Vue component.

I have tried to find each component using `$refs` and if found, add the class name to the element's class list. The class is added, but it is removed as soon as user interaction begins (e.g. the component is clicked, receives new value etc.)

Here is some sample code I've tried:

```
beforeCreate() {
    let requiredFields = config.requiredFields
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        requiredFields.forEach(field => {
            if(this.$refs[field]) {      
                this.$refs[field].$el.classList.add('my-class')
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Usually, you can add classes dynamically in the template using `v-bind:class`. Do you really have to assign classes using $ref elements?

Comment: Why can't you use something like `:class="{'my-class': requiredFields.includes('fieldName')}"` instaed of `ref="fieldName"`?

Comment: I would like to avoid adding it like that to all components from template. Furthermore, I want it to be configurable via the config file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

```
this.$refs[field].$el.classList.value = this.$refs[field].$el.classList.value + 'my-class'
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question was posted ages ago, but I was playing around with something similar and came across a much easier way to add a class to $refs.

When we reference `this.$refs['some-ref'].$el.classList` it becomes a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) which has a bunch of methods and properties you can access.

In this instance, to add a class it is as simple as

```
this.$refs['some-ref'].$el.classList.add('some-class')
```

Answer (score 2):

the only thing that you need to make sure of is that your `config.requiredFields` must include the ref name as a `string` and nothing more or less ... you can achieve that with :

```
   //for each ref you have 
    for (let ref in this.$refs) {
        config.requiredFields.push(ref)
     }
   // so config.requiredFields will look like this : ['one','two]
```

here is an example of a working sample :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('one', {
  template: '<p>component number one</p>'
})
Vue.component('two', {
  template: '<p>component number two</p>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  beforeCreate() {
    let requiredFields = ['one','two'] //  config.requiredFields should be like this
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        requiredFields.forEach(field => {
            if(this.$refs[field]) {      
                this.$refs[field].$el.classList.add('my-class')
            }
        })
    })
}
})
```

```css
.my-class {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <one ref="one" ></one>
  <two ref="two" ></two>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is exactly how my config looks like. As I mentioned, the class is successfuly added to the components, but as soon as I click into e.g. v-text-field, the class is removed... I don’t understabd why this happens.

Comment: @trix ah , if yo u can create a sample template on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) or codepen / jsfiddle will be easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

You've to make sure classList.value is an array. By default its a string.

```
methods: {
    onClick(ref) {
      const activeClass = 'active-submenu'
      if (!this.$refs[ref].classList.length) {
        this.$refs[ref].classList.value = [activeClass]
      } else {
        this.$refs[ref].classList.value = ''
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

this post helped me tremendously. I needed to target an element within a v-for loop and I ended up writing a little method for it (i'm using Quasar/Vue).
hopefully this will save someone else some time.

```
addStyleToRef: function(referEl, indexp, classToAdd) {
            //will add a class to a $ref element (even within a v-for loop) 
            //supply $ref name (referEl - txt), index within list (indexp - int) & css class name (classToAdd txt)
            if ( this.$refs[referEl][indexp].$el.classList.value.includes(classToAdd) ){
                console.log('class already added')
            } else {
                this.$refs[referEl][indexp].$el.classList.value = this.$refs[referEl][indexp].$el.classList.value + ' ' + classToAdd
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let tag = this.$refs[ref-key][0];
$(tag).addClass('d-none');
```

Simply get the tag with ref `let tag = this.$refs[ref-key][0];` then put this tag into jquery object `$(tag).addClass('d-none');` class will be added to required tag.